# how to remove items from list which are present side by side in another list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
grt=["thousand","million","billion","trillion","quadrillion","quintillion","sextillion","septillion","octillion","nonillion","decillion","undecillion","duodecillion","tredecillion","quattuor-decillion","quindecillion","sexdecillion","septen-decillion","octodecillion","novemdecillion","vigintillion"]


e=["sixty","million","billion","trillion","quadrillion","quintillion","sextillion","septillion","octillion"]

def sep():
    global e
    global grt

    for i in range(1,len(e)):
        if (e[i] in grt and e[i-1] in grt)==True:
            e.remove(e[i])

while all(((i in grt) and (e[e.index(i)-1] in grt)) for i in e[1:len(e)])!=False:
    sep()
print(e)
```

i am expecting that the last statement print(e) would print ["sixty"] but its not printing that.

Comment: You should not remove and iterate at the same time.

Comment: I think you want `[j for i, j in zip(grt, e) if i != j]`

Comment: ...or `print([e[i] for i in range(len(e)) if e[i]!=grt[i]])`

Answer (score 0):

Filter function is perfect for such application.

```py
grt=["thousand","million","billion","trillion","quadrillion","quintillion","sextillion","septillion","octillion","nonillion","decillion","undecillion","duodecillion","tredecillion","quattuor-decillion","quindecillion","sexdecillion","septen-decillion","octodecillion","novemdecillion","vigintillion"]


e=["sixty","million","billion","trillion","quadrillion","quintillion","sextillion","septillion","octillion"]

results = list(filter(lambda x:  x not in grt, e))
print(results)
```